# rsync all files of remote machine over SSH without root user?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, backup, rsync

I have this command to backup a remote machine. The problem is that I need root rights to read and copy all files. I have no root user enabled for security reasons and use `sudo` the Ubuntu way. Would I need some cool piping or something to do this?

```
rsync -chavzP --stats user@192.168.1.2:/ /media/backupdisk/myserverbackup/
```

Comment: Just use the `root` account in the first place. `sudo`, especially combined with `NOPASSWD` as recommended in the comments, doesn't really improve the security of your machine.

Comment: ssh for root is disabled for security.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I would recommend that you just use the root account in the first place. If you set it up like this:

- Configure your `sshd_config` on the target machine to `PermitRootLogin without-password`.
- Use `ssh-keygen` on the machine that pulls the backup to create an SSH private key (only if you don't already have an SSH key). Do not set a passphrase. Google a tutorial if you need details for this, there should be plenty.
- Append the contents of `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` of the backup machine to the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` of your target machine.
- Now your backup machine has root access to your target machine, without having to use password authentication.

then the resulting setup should be pretty safe.

---

`sudo`, especially combined with `NOPASSWD` as recommended in the comments, has no security benefits over just using the root account. For example this suggestion:

> add the following to your `/etc/sudoers` file: `rsyncuser ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync`

essentially gives `rsyncuser` root permissions anyway. You ask:

> @MartinvonWittich Easy to gain a full root shell because `rsync` executed with `sudo`? Walk [m]e [through] that please.

Well, simple. With the recommended configuration, `rsyncuser` may now run `rsync` as root without even being asked for a password. `rsync` is a very powerful tool to manipulate files, so now `rsyncuser` has a very powerful tool to manipulate files with root permissions. Finding a way to exploit this took me just a few minutes (tested on Ubuntu 13.04, requires `dash`, `bash` didn't work):

```
martin@martin ~ % sudo rsync --perms --chmod u+s /bin/dash /bin/rootdash
martin@martin ~ % rootdash
# whoami
root
# touch /etc/evil
# tail -n1 /etc/shadow
dnsmasq:*:15942:0:99999:7:::
```

As you can see, I have created myself a root shell; `whoami` identifies my account as root, I can create files in `/etc`, and I can read from `/etc/shadow`. My exploit was to set the [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bit on the `dash` binary; it causes Linux to always run that binary with the permissions of the owner, in this case root.

> Having a real root is not [recommended] for good reasons. – redanimalwar 15 hours ago

No, clumsily working around the root account in situations where it is absolutely appropriate to use it is not for good reasons. This is just another form of [cargo cult programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) - you don't really understand the concept behind sudo vs root, you just blindly apply the belief "root is bad, sudo is good" because you've read that somewhere.

On the one hand, there are situations where `sudo` is definitely the right tool for the job. For example, when you're interactively working on a graphical Linux desktop, let's say Ubuntu, then having to use `sudo` is fine in those rare cases where you sometimes need root access. Ubuntu intentionally has a disabled root account and forces you to use `sudo` by default to prevent users from just always using the root account to log in. When the user just wants to use e.g. the web browser, then logging in as root would be a dangerous thing, and therefore not having a root account by default prevents stupid people from doing this.

On the other hand, there are situations like yours, where an automated script requires root permissions to something, for example to make a backup. Now using `sudo` to work around the root account is not only pointless, it's also dangerous: at first glance `rsyncuser` looks like an ordinary unprivileged account. But as I've already explained, it would be very easy for an attacker to gain full root access if he had already gained `rsyncuser` access. So essentially, you now have an additional root account that doesn't look like a root account at all, which is not a good thing.

Comment: Nice explanation. Would another reason for using sudo over root be in the situation where multiple people have sysadmin roles on a server? This way each can use their own SSH keys instead of sharing the SSH key of root?

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh you could just as easy put all SSH keys into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, or even create multiple root accounts with different homes so each user can have his own shell, home and `.ssh/authorized_keys` :)

Comment: good points. However one can provide a script that only rsyncs specific paths and permit sudo on that

Comment: You can restrict ssh keys to only allowing certain commands, too.  Definitely a good idea, since if you're automating something, you will probably be making these ssh keys without any passphrase, or at least so they're accessible all the time a machine is running.  (meaning that root on that machine grants access to root on other machines.)

Comment: Martin's concerns regarding using sudo root are valid, but it seems they could be mitigated by specifying the exact rsync parameters in the sudoers file. According to the sudoers(5) man page on Ubuntu: "If a Cmnd has associated command line arguments, then the arguments in
 the Cmnd must match exactly those given by the user on the command line (or match the wildcards if there are any)." If the sudoers file specifies the exact rsync command with the exact options (including source and destination), then it seems it should be safe.

Comment: It is possible to restrict a ssh to to a specific command **with** specific augments. Yes, this can take more effort to cover your use cases, but it will block the command if it has the wrong augments.

Comment: One consideration not brought up earlier: `sshd` generally does *not* log which authorized key was used to connect to an account, so if you connect as `bob` then `sudo`, you get a better audit trail than if you connect in to `root` directly with `bob`'s key.

Comment: „So essentially, you now have an additional root account that doesn't look like a root account at all, which is not a good thing.“ – As opposed to making bob an account with remote root privileges? How is that better? My solution was to add the public key of my localhost root account to the authorized_keys of the remote root. That way, only a root can ssh as a root to the remote station.

Comment: @Witiko yes, using the root account is exactly what I argued for.

Comment: I see. Using `~` in the bullet points made it seem like you were referring to the home directory of a regular user account rather than to `/root/`. Should've read the answer more carefully, but it wouldn't hurt to expand the `~` to make it explicit what account is being discussed.

Comment: @Witiko fixed :)

Comment: The first point *"Configure your sshd_config on the target machine to PermitRootLogin without-password"* is disconcerting making me wonder about security holes.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix why? `without-password` means only via SSH keys, and SSH keys are generally considered very safe. And root logins in situations where they are necessary are fine, IMO.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That command ("without-password") was poorly named :) A modern man page states it this way: `If this option is set to prohibit-password (or its deprecated alias, without-password), password and keyboard-interactive authentication are disabled for root.`

Answer (score 83):

Make use of the `--rsync-path` option to make the remote `rsync` command run with `sudo` privileges. Your command should then be e.g.:

```
rsync -chavzP --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --stats user@192.168.1.2:/ .
```

If `sudo` prompts you for a password, you have to avoid that either by using a `NOPASSWD` privilege with the remote user account (pointless for root, may make sense in other use cases), or if you don't want to do that:

- Make sure that the option `tty_tickets` is disabled for the user you
  are using, by running e.g. `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/local-rsync`
  and entering:

  ```
  Defaults:your.username.for.rsync !tty_tickets
  ```
- Make sure that the option `requiretty` is disabled for the user you are
  using - it could be off by default. The method is the same as above.
- Seed the `sudo` password on the remote machine, by running e.g.
  `ssh -t user@192.168.1.2 sudo`

Comment: For this I would have to step rsync to not ask for password on the remote? like it the example? Because this commands gets me a error. I tryed echo <pw> | sudo -S rsync" and some <<<EOF stuff i found here http://www.shermann.name/2011/02/sudo-over-ssh-magic.html neither did work. But I am not sure how to type this mutiline thing into the console and if this works over ssh or if it sould be `\n` like its show below on that site.

Comment: You should use SSH authentication via a public key instead of a password.

Comment: @scai the password that is asked for is most likely the `sudo` password, not the `ssh` password

Comment: @redanimalwar allows your user to `sudo /usr/bin/rsync` without asking for a passphrase; check `man sudoers` for how to do this; you might want to create an extra backup user for this.

Comment: To allow  `sudo /usr/bin/rsync` to run without requiring as password add the following to your `/etc/sudoers` file: `rsyncuser ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync` This will allow the user rsyncuser (as mentioned above it would be best to create a dedicated backup user) with the username you want.

Comment: @M_dk now `rsync` essentially always has root permissions; it's probably very easy to gain a full root shell in that account. I think it's better to just use the real root account in the first place.

Comment: @M_dk dedicated Backup user is a good idea! For security.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich Easy to gain a full root shell because rsync executed with sudo? Walk be trough that please. Having a real root is not reconnected for good reasons.

Comment: @redanimalwar please see my answer to the question for a detailed explanation.

Comment: i find that editing the sudoers file to remove `tty_tickets` is a security issue, since I would rather avoid that i wrote up a different way of doing this in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124172/copy-a-local-file-to-a-remote-server-non-root-privileges-over-sudo/126503#126503

Comment: @redanimalwar and @M_dk: I agree with Martin.  If you want to automate rsync-as-root, do it with ssh keys.  `echo "password" | something` in a script is FAR worse.  Allowing passwordless `sudo rsync` isn't much better; almost certainly a bigger hole than requiring an SSH private key that's only stored on the machine you want to give access to.  The reason this answer is useful is for interactive one-off cases, not automation.  (although I found the ssh-askpass answer below more useful for a one-off, since I didn't have to disable `tty_tickets`)

Comment: The answer in no way speaking of `echo "password" | something` I actually never used this and agree with the security problems coming with letting sudoless execution of rsync (also not suggested here) is bad. What the `tty_tickets` does I have actually no idea, seems needed and a security issue. This would work securely without tweaking anything by just running sodo on ssh and then executing the command right? But since I asked that question for scriping purposes, I totally agree that key based ssh without pw is the secure and right was to do. I accepted Martins answer instead.

Comment: Sill I think a disabled root account is actually a good security measure. Because a hacker has 50% with that already if you happen to have passwords enabled. So to be (very) secure I would advice to disable password via remote logins (possible I guess) and only used key based logins after re-enabling root and setting up passwordless ssh on Ubuntu. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Answer (score 17):

One simple way to do this is to use the graphical `ssh-askpass` program with `sudo`, this gets around the fact that `sudo` is not connected to the terminal and allows you to enter the password safely:

```
rsync -chavzPe 'ssh -X' --stats \
  --rsync-path='SUDO_ASKPASS=/usr/lib/ssh/x11-ssh-askpass sudo -A rsync' \
  user@192.168.1.2:/ .
```

Of course the `ssh-askpass` program must be installed in the given location and you must be running an X session on the machine you are working on. There are a few variations on the `ssh-askpass` program which should also work (Gnome/KDE versions). Also a graphical `sudo` replacement program like `gksu` or `kdesudo` should also work.

Comment: `rsync --rsh='ssh -X'  --rsync-path='gksudo -- rsync' user@host:/ .` doesn't work.  `rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1634) [server=3.1.1]`.  Oh, ubuntu does ship gnome-ssh-askpass, but it's `/usr/bin/ssh-askpass`, instead of `/usr/lib/ssh/x11...`.  So that worked :)

Comment: This is one of the better solutions as it doesn't need any reconfiguration on the other end -- just needs the askpass installed and X forwarding enabled, both of which should be fairly common.

Comment: Works like a charm after installing `ssh-askpass`. I just had to look up the meaning of `-chavzPe`, would be great to spell these out as long options.

Comment: I tried this, but the prompt is opening on the remote machine and is not being forwarded to the local machine. X11Forwarding is working ask expected, which I verified by running `xeyes` using SSH.

Answer (score 7):

If your user has already sudo privileges which are protected with a password I would keep them as-is and only add a stanza to use rsync without a password:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%admin ALL= NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync
```

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this problem today and solved it without the need for modifying configuration files or granting root-level permissions to user accounts. My particular set-up was that user `A` on machine `foo` had to copy all of the user directories from `foo` to machine `bar` in a `backup` directory that user `A` owned. (User `A` has sudo privileges on `foo`.)

The command I used is below. It was invoked by user `A` in the `/home` directory on `foo`.

```
sudo rsync -avu -e "ssh -i /home/A/.ssh/id_rsa -l A"  * B:/home/backup
```

This runs rsync as sudo so that all user directories on `foo` can be accessed but it tells rsync to use ssh to access machine `bar` using user `A`'s credentials. My needs were slightly different than the question above but this allowed me to quickly get a backup of all the user directories on a particular machine I manage without mucking with the system's configuration.

Comment: This is brilliant. I forgot about the `-i` option to `ssh`. You can use `--rsync-path="sudo /usr/bin/rsync" ` if you have sudo on machine `bar`. This then does reading as `root@foo` and writing as `root@bar`, but transferring via `A@foo` -> `B@bar`. Thanks!

Comment: It will not preserve owner (e.g. root), am I right?

Comment: This was the answer that solved it for me after two days of trying various options. I could ssh into my server without a password but rsync continually asked for one. The important part is `--rsh='ssh -i path/to/id_rsa'` which tells rsync to use the ssh key when logging in ( `--rsh` is the long form of `-e` ). The full command is `sudo rsync [options] --rsh='ssh -i path/to/id_rsa' /local/path root@myserver.com:/remote/path`.

Answer (score 4):

Running rsync as daemon on the target machine allows you to do what you want.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but it would be better w/ some explanation of how to get the rsynch daemon running, and how you use it w/ root access.

Comment: rsync as daemon wouldn't match this case, because rsync will drop root permissions even when started as root then not all files could be transferred.

Comment: @teissler Please explain which root permissions are "dropped"? As far as I know, you only need to set `uid = root` and `gid = root` in the module config to use a specific rsyncd user (which are all separate from usual linux users) to copy all files, even those with root permissions. Finally it's much safer than all other described methods in the other answers as no root SSH access is needed and you can force ready-only.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` but it ask for password, workaround:

```
rsync -chavzP --stats --rsync-path="echo <SUDOPASS> | sudo -Sv && sudo rsync"  user@192.168.1.2:/ .
```

Comment: It usually isn't a good idea to put passwords into a command line one-liner; they become visible in the process tree, for example. I sometimes replace the actual password in this type of statement with `$( cat my_password.txt )` which is slightly better, but it is usually preferred to configure the permissions on either end, and/or use SSH keys, in such a way that passwords aren't required on the CLI

Answer (score -1):

Re-vitalizing this old thread, as still valid....
To restrict root access across server using pre-shared keys I recommend:

A) Restrict ssh-in for root in sshd

Put this into /etc/sshd/sshd_config on the client at the end (may also be in authorized keys):

```
Match User root
    AllowUsers root@<(dirvish) servers from which access to root is granted>
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTTY no
```

B) Force command (I did this in authorized keys, may also be in sshd_config)

```
command="/root/.ssh/allowed_commands.sh 2> /root/.ssh/allowed_commands_`/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S`_stderr.log" ssh-rsa ..... (here goes the key) ......
```

C) Wrapper script /root/.ssh/allowed_commands.sh Rights: 700
This is based on
https://serverfault.com/questions/749474/ssh-authorized-keys-command-option-multiple-commands

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# You can have only one forced command in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. Use this
# wrapper to allow several commands.

MY_PATH=`pwd`/.ssh
BASENAME=`basename $0`
STDOUT_LOG_FILE=${MY_PATH}/${BASENAME%.sh}_`/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S`_stdout.log
find ${MY_PATH}/${BASENAME%.sh}*.log -ctime +4 | tee ${MY_PATH}/${BASENAME%.sh}_deleted_`/bin/date +\%Y-\%m-\%d_\%H-\%M-\%S`.log | xargs rm -f
# skip stdout? "rsync" commands have huge output and will flood FS....
# List here those which not to log stdout
COMMANDS_TO_SKIP_STDOUT=(rsync cat)

date >&2
echo I am instructed to run >&2
echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND >&2
# skip stdout of the comand?
SKIP_STDOUT=0
for i in ${COMMANDS_TO_SKIP_STDOUT[@]}; do
 FOUND_SKIP_CMMAND=`expr "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" : $i`
 if (( ${FOUND_SKIP_CMMAND} > 0 )) ; then 
  SKIP_STDOUT=1
 fi
done

case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
 "rsync --server --sender -vlkHogDtpre.iLsfxC --numeric-ids . <path 1>"     | \
 "rsync --server --sender -vlkHogDtpre.iLsfxC --numeric-ids . <path 2>/"    | \
 "rsync --server --sender -vlkHogDtpre.iLsfxC --numeric-ids . <path 3>/"    | \
 "cat /etc/hosts"                            | \
 "ls -alt /etc")
 # last entries for testing
 if (( ${SKIP_STDOUT} > 0 )) ; then 
      $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND 
      RET_CODE=$?
  else
      $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND | tee ${STDOUT_LOG_FILE}
      RET_CODE=$?
  fi
  echo "command executed" >&2
  echo "return code: " $RET_CODE >&2
  echo "output on stdout (this is the output to stderr)" >&2
  ;;
 *)
  echo "Access denied" | tee ${STDOUT_LOG_FILE}
  echo "Not in the list of allowed commands! Access denied" >&2
  echo "command not executed" >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

So there is always a log (written to stderr and stored in /root/.ssh) at least from the latest run in which you can see what the command was.

If you want to set up a new command, just run it and check the stderr log.

stdout is also logged and as well passed back to the calling process, but is omitted for some commands (E.g. rsyncs would flood your filesystem)
Logs are deleted in order not to eat storage.

(All set up in my systems and working perfect)

Still a lot of degrees of freedom, but I think this explains the idea :-)

Any Comments?

Bestest

Thilo

Comment: This question is over 7 years old and already has an accepted answer