# scripting copy of remote root-owned files when 'PermitRootLogin no'

Tags: ssh, sudo, remote

I'm setting up a cloud node (only ssh-accessible, GUIs deprecated, running Debian 7) with 'PermitRootLogin no' for security. For some applications I want to copy some root-owned config files from the remote to local (e.g., to setup a local client). And, for reproducibility, I want to script this (having already hosed things a few times from malformed commandlines). What's best practice to enable getting remote `sudo` **from a script** (and, yes, I know I'll hafta type the password--*complete* non-interactivity would be nice but is not a requirement), given 'PermitRootLogin no' (and no physical access)? Some things I've tried:

(1) `scp`: fails because I can't tell `scp` I want to be `sudo` remotely. (AFAICS--am I missing something?)

(2) naked `rsync-path`: I tried

```
me@local ~ $ rsync --rsync-path='sudo rsync' remote:/path/to/file ${HOME}/backups/cloud_9/path/to/file
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
...
```

Can one enable a non-graphical askpass? Casual [DuckDuckGo](http://donttrack.us/)-ing did not find. Note `rsync-path` *will* (IIRC) work with 'visiblepw' but not nakedly/without.

(3) `sudoers.d/visiblepw`: DDG found

```
http://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2009-August/004142.html
> [sudo-users] Error: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
> Todd C. Miller Todd.Miller at courtesan.com
> Mon Aug 3 10:43:04 EDT 2009

> Recent versions of sudo will refuse to prompt for a password if no tty is present,
> since it is not possible to turn off echo in this case. You can [enable this]
> with a line like:

> Defaults visiblepw
```

so I created

```
me@remote:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/visiblepw 
> Defaults  visiblepw
```

which works, but, as noted, `echo`s pw when `sudo`ing remotely ... but now I can, e.g., `ssh remote 'sudo whatever'` ... as long as no one can see my shell :-)

I'd like to know, is there A Better Way to do this? Am I missing something? Note again, I want it to work from a script.

One more thing (noted while writing), which I found while writing, and haven't tried, because it looks ugly:

(4) [`mkfifo` hoop-jumping](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126503/38638): looks ugly and not-quite-scriptable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does it have to be all client-side? Otherwise, you could break it into two parts, one where the client `scps` the files to the cloud node, and a `cron` job on the cloud node that fixes the permissions, ownership and location of the files. You might have to wait for a minute for the cron job to run, ( or you culd have a cron job which runs every minute, and loops 4 times every 15 seconds using `sleep`. It should involve a minimum of work, and be fairly easy to diagnose any issues.

Comment: @Warwick: the usecase specifies copying from remote to local, not vv.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this might be [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) - a configuration management tool that interacts with the remotes via ssh. It greatly simplifies the task of ssh authentication and sudo or su on the remote.

With Ansible installed and a host inventory configured, the command to perform this operation is:

```
ansible remotehost -m fetch -a "src=/etc/sudoers dest=remote-soduers" -u root --sudo --ask-sudo-pass
```

If you need to configure a bare-bones inventory:

```
cat > hosts <<EOF
[remotes]
remotehosts
EOF
ansible -i hosts remotehost -m fetch -a "src=/etc/sudoers dest=remote-soduers" -u root --sudo --ask-sudo-pass
```

Alternately, a quick one time command might be accomplished by using the '-t' option on ssh to force pseudo-terminal allocation:

```
ssh -t remotehost "sudo rsync -av /path/on/remote localuser@localhost:/path/on/local"
```

This most likely results in two password prompts: one for the sudo, and one for the connection back into the local from root@remote.

Comment: I am just a coder who needs to set something up for some idiots, not a real admin. I *know* real admins who very much like Ansible (and Puppet, and even Chef), but ... isn't that a rather big hammer for this particular usecase? I.e., at this point, I'm just trying to get some files off a box.

Comment: Learning the whole Ansible tool is a big hammer - but if you can apt or yum install it easily, small crisp command lines are possible, and they don't require remote daemons - just ssh access. Added an example above.

Comment: @R Perrin: "Added [Ansible] example above"

Thanks! I'll give that a shot when I get a chance. FWIW, `visiblepw` suffices for now ... with caveat="check for local physical lurkers first" :-(