# How to send sudo password over pipe?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sudo, pipe, sshd

I need to replace existing sshd config on the remote PC and restart sshd, so I try to use this:

```
cat /sshd_cfg | ssh user@192.168.0.47 "cat > /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd restart"
```

but I get **bash: /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission Denied**

So to use sudo I try "*echo pass | sudo -S*" like that: `cat /sshd_cfg | ssh user@192.168.0.47 "echo pass | sudo -S cat > /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd restart"`
but getting the same output - Permission Denied, may be because of pipes collision? What shall I do?

```
Linux 190 4.3.0-2-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 4 20:36:35 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

**

- upd

As I found, the problem is in user privileges.

If I connect *directly* to PC and try to execute `sudo cat /dev/null > /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I get Permission Denied, but it' okay If I try `sudo -H -u root bash -c 'cat /dev/null > /etc/ssh/sshd_config'`.

So I tried that from remote: `cat /sshd_cfg | ssh user@IP "echo password | sudo -S -H -u root bash -c 'cat > /etc/ssh/sshd_config'"`

And this time no errors appeares. And the file was changed, but it became ...blank. Instead `cat`ing /sshd_cfg in it.

Why?

Comment: Where in that command did you put `sudo`?

Comment: Why not just `scp sshd_cfg root@192.168.0.47:/etc/ssh`?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich at this level you probably need to assume that `sshd` is configured to prevent root logins

Comment: @roaima like that: cat /sshd_cfg | ssh user@192.168.0.47 "echo pass | sudo -S cat > /etc/ssh/sshd_config && service sshd restart"

Comment: @roaima Then that should be changed. Piping plaintext passwords into `sudo` is a hell of a lot worse than e.g. allowing root logins with a SSH key. My answer to a similar question explains in detail why using `sudo` this way is a bad idea: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92123/rsync-all-files-of-remote-machine-over-ssh-without-root-user/92397#92397

Comment: @MartinvonWittich `ssh` does allow root logins with a key. It doesn't permit root logins with password. Given the level of this question I was trying to suggest we (all) assume that no certificates had been set up and so no root login could directly be used. _Very happy_ to be proven wrong, though, as that avoids the abhorrence that is `sudo -S`